# Failed in Tensorflow Serving gRPC reflection

Tags: tensorflow, reflection, grpc

I'm trying to add a gRPC health check endpoint in tensorflow serving. I added these code into tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server.cc and re-compiled it:

```
::grpc::EnableDefaultHealthCheckService(true);
::grpc::reflection::InitProtoReflectionServerBuilderPlugin();
```

After that I run it and test with grpcurl: `grpcurl -plaintext localhost:8500 list`
It shows:

```
grpc.health.v1.Health
grpc.reflection.v1alpha.ServerReflection 
tensorflow.ProfilerService 
tensorflow.serving.ModelService 
tensorflow.serving.PredictionService
```

But when I try `grpcurl -plaintext localhost:8500 grpc.health.v1.Health/Check`
It says:

```
Error invoking method "grpc.health.v1.Health/Check": target server does not expose service "grpc.health.v1.Health"
```

It's quite a simple feature but have been stucking me for several days.
Could someone help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply speaking, grpcurl relies on reflection service if you don't provide proto files and gRPC C++ doesn't expose reflection data for health service, which is why you got this head-scratching error in the first place.

```
$ grpcurl -plaintext 0.0.0.0:50051 grpc.health.v1.Health/Check
Error invoking method "grpc.health.v1.Health/Check": target server does not expose service "grpc.health.v1.Health"
```

grpcurl can do health-check call with health proto file present;

```
$ grpcurl -plaintext -proto=src/proto/grpc/health/v1/health.proto 0.0.0.0:50051 grpc.health.v1.Health/Check
{
  "status": "SERVING"
}
```

Implementation-wise, gRPC C++ relies on protobuf description pool to implement its reflection service but health is based on upb which is not part of protobuf description pool. This is why gRPC C++ isn't able to expose the schema of health service.